# Convert AD Timestamps to .Net DateTime

Tags: datetime, active-directory

In active directory there are a bunch of INT64 fields (like lastlogintimestamp, accountexpires, etc)

How do I convert these to datetime values in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://securitythroughabsurdity.com/2005/12/active-directory-and.html

What that says, is the correct function is `DateTime.FromFileTime`, which returns a DateTime object, which is exactly what you need.

Comment: For the record, so does this:

DateTime root = new DateTime(1601, 1, 1);
DateTime utc = root.AddTicks(timestamp);
DateTime local = utc.ToLocalTime();
return local;

Comment: Where timestamp is the INT64 value from AD.
Also note that a Int64 value of 9223372036854775807 is the equivelent of null/no value.

Comment: Good catch on the null/no value.  That other solution is mentioned in the link I posted.

Answer (score 1):

The working example below shows how to do it in PowerShell using .NET, which also illustrates how you would do it in C#:

```
$timestamp=129699324000000000
[System.DateTime]::FromFileTime($timestamp)

Monday, January 02, 2012 12:00:00 AM
```